# Wireframe: Legend colors with multiple surfaces and transparency

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, wireframe

The following code plots 3 colored planes using lattice's wireframe function. However, I cannot understand why the legend does not change by setting the color groups. I tried to do it manually but I only ended up changing the text color. By the way, does anyone also know how to make the surface transparent by 70%?

```
library(lattice)
library(akima)

SurfaceData <- data.frame(
               x=rep(seq(0,100,length.out=10),each=10,times=3),
               y=rep(rep(seq(0,100,length.out=10),times=10),times=3),
               z=c(rep(25,100),seq(30,70,length.out=100),seq(95,75,length.out=100)),
               type=factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),each=100))
                          )

wireframe(z~x*y,data=SurfaceData,group=type,
          col.groups=c("red","green","blue"),
          scales = list(arrows=FALSE, col="black",font=10),
          xlab = list("Variable X",rot=30),
          ylab = list("Variable Y",rot=-30),
          zlab = list("Variable Z",rot=90),
          zlim = c(0,100),
          #auto.key=TRUE,
          auto.key=list(text=c("A","B","C"),col=c("red","green","blue"),lines=TRUE),
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
          )
```

The result:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change colors of lines, you should replace `auto.key` with `key` and supply list of values for texts and lines.

```
wireframe(z~x*y,data=SurfaceData,group=type,
          col.groups=c("red","green","blue"),
          scales = list(arrows=FALSE, col="black",font=10),
          xlab = list("Variable X",rot=30),
          ylab = list("Variable Y",rot=-30),
          zlab = list("Variable Z",rot=90),
          zlim = c(0,100),
          key=list(text=list(c("A","B","C"),col=c("red","green","blue")),
                   lines=list(lty=c(1,1,1),col=c("red","green","blue"))),
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
)
```

To make colors transparent you can use function `rgb()`. Here I define new variable `mycolors.trans` that contain transparent colors and `mycolors` with the same colors but not transparent for legend entries.

```
mycolors.trans = rgb(c(255,0,0), 
               c(0,255,0), 
               c(0,0,255),alpha = 70,maxColorValue = 255) 

mycolors = rgb(c(255,0,0), 
                     c(0,255,0), 
                     c(0,0,255),maxColorValue = 255) 

wireframe(z~x*y,data=SurfaceData,group=type,
          col.groups=mycolors.trans,
          scales = list(arrows=FALSE, col="black",font=10),
          xlab = list("Variable X",rot=30),
          ylab = list("Variable Y",rot=-30),
          zlab = list("Variable Z",rot=90),
          zlim = c(0,100),
          #auto.key=TRUE,
          key=list(text=list(c("A","B","C"),col=mycolors),
                   lines=list(lty=c(1,1,1),col=mycolors)),
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

see ?`simpleTheme` , for the transparence part

```
    par.settings =  simpleTheme(alpha = 0.7)
```